# redirecting urls with ASCII characters in them

Tags: .htaccess, ascii

I'm working on a site which has some pretty awful urls to redirect, for example:-

```
/sites/default/files/files/National%20Commission%20of%20Enquiry%20-%20Intensive%20Alternative%20to%20Custody%20in%20Greater%20Manchester.doc
```

Doing this (removing the ASCII spaces) results in a 500 error:-

```
redirect 301 /sites/default/files/files/National Commission of Enquiry - Intensive Alternative to Custody in Greater Manchester.doc http://www.makejusticework.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/National-Commission-of-Enquiry-Intensive-Alternative-to-Custody-in-Greater-Manchester-1.pdf
```

Preserving the spaces as %20 simply 404's. I assume its the ASCII characters that are getting in the way - is there a reliable way to redirect urls such as this one?

Comment: try replacing the %-encoded characters with the characters themselves. Because you have some spaces in there you would need to put the url between quotes (`"/sites/.../space here"`). Giving us your current, not working, code would also be helpful.

Comment: @Gerben I've just updated the question with a non-working example.

Comment: @Gerben putting the url in quotes after removing the ASCII characters fixed the problem. Please post that as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the %-encoded characters with the characters themselves. Because you have some spaces in there you would need to put the url between quotes ("/sites/.../space here")

So in your case:

```
redirect 301 "/sites/default/files/files/National Commission of Enquiry - Intensive Alternative to Custody in Greater Manchester.doc" http://www.makejusticework.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/National-Commission-of-Enquiry-Intensive-Alternative-to-Custody-in-Greater-Manchester-1.pdf
```